# Combine prices from different categories on the same date in one table using SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have one long table of stock returns for around 20 stocks. The stock symbol is a category. For example, assume the table has: [Date, Close, Symbol] where there are 20,000 rows with 20 different stock symbols.

```
|Date .    |Close|Symbol|
|2010-01-01|20.10|SPY|
|2010-01-02|20.11|SPY|
|2010-01-02|30.11|CWGIX|
|2010-01-02|40.10|PG|
|2010-01-03|32.10|CWGIX|
|2010-01-04|41.10|PG|
|2010-01-04|30.02|CWGIX|
```

The problem is that the stocks all have different start and stop dates. If I want to find the set of closing prices for two stocks that occur on the same days, I currently have to run:

```
SELECT
  spy.Date, cwgix.Close cwgix, spy.Close spy
FROM (
  SELECT DATE(Date) Date, Close FROM `mytable` WHERE Symbol = "CWGIX ORDER BY Date ASC) cwgix
JOIN (
  SELECT DATE(Date) Date, Close FROM `mytable` WHERE Symbol = "SPY" ORDER BY Date ASC) spy
ON
  cwgix.Date = spy.Date
```

This gives me:

```
|Date      |SPY  |CWGIX|PG   |
|2010-01-02|20.11|30.11|40.10|
```

etc

How can I do this for all 20 stocks? I'm thinking there is a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: provide some sample data and expected output - so we actually can help you :o)

Comment: Do you want a cross product or do you want every stock in the same table

Comment: I want a row for each date that has a closing price for each stock, which I'm pretty sure is a cross product. This would mean no NaNs or empty rows, but I would be interested in how to do both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT Date,
  MAX(IF(Symbol = 'SPY', Close, NULL)) SPY,
  MAX(IF(Symbol = 'CWGIX', Close, NULL)) CWGIX,
  MAX(IF(Symbol = 'ABC', Close, NULL)) ABC,
  MAX(IF(Symbol = 'XYZ', Close, NULL)) XYZ
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY Date
```

You will need as many below lines in above script as many Symbols you have  - which is 20 per what you stated in your question

```
MAX(IF(Symbol = 'SymbolName', Close, NULL)) SymbolName,
```

> I'm interested in both

If you need ONLY dates where ALL Symbols have Close value  - you can use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DATE,
  MAX(IF(Symbol = 'SPY', Close, NULL)) SPY,
  MAX(IF(Symbol = 'CWGIX', Close, NULL)) CWGIX,
  MAX(IF(Symbol = 'PG', Close, NULL)) PG
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY DATE) t
WHERE NOT TO_JSON_STRING(t) LIKE '%null%'
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2010-01-01' DATE, 20.10 Close, 'SPY' Symbol UNION ALL
  SELECT '2010-01-02', 20.11, 'SPY' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2010-01-02', 30.11, 'CWGIX' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2010-01-02', 40.10, 'PG' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2010-01-03', 32.10, 'CWGIX' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2010-01-04', 41.10, 'PG' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2010-01-04', 30.02, 'CWGIX' 
)
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DATE,
  MAX(IF(Symbol = 'SPY', Close, NULL)) SPY,
  MAX(IF(Symbol = 'CWGIX', Close, NULL)) CWGIX,
  MAX(IF(Symbol = 'PG', Close, NULL)) PG
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY DATE) t
WHERE NOT TO_JSON_STRING(t) LIKE '%null%'
```

with result

```
Row DATE        SPY     CWGIX   PG   
1   2010-01-02  20.11   30.11   40.1
```

Comment: Cool -- so I have to fix the columns, I can't do a select distinct Symbol from `project.dataset.table`, but this is a clever solution.

Comment: It is not clear - please clarify - do you want only dates where ALL (not just some) stocks have Closing value?

Comment: I'm interested in both. This solution and the solution where a row has a complete set of closing values. Sorry, I wasn't more clear.

Comment: I'm also curious why I'm getting "None" and "NaN" responses, for example: Date G_Fund F_Fund S_Fund I_Fund C_Fund CCWAX CWGIX CWIAX PRRCX 
0 1970-01-02 None None None None None NaN NaN

Comment: what is the data type of `Close` column?

Comment: float or double

Comment: see update for "both thing". as of None or NaN you need provide more details and maybe some specific examples